# Using curl to fetch MediaWiki page info through SSO redirects

Tags: curl, mediawiki, ntlm

**tl;dr**: HTTP request to URL works through Chrome and Firefox, but fails using `curl`.

**Details**:

My company uses MediaWiki for an Intranet wiki. My application used to successfully use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) to fetch information about pages using this command:

`curl -s -k -u "username:password" "https://wiki.intranet/mainwiki/api.php?action=query&titles=SomePage&prop=info&format=xml"`

However, the IT department has recently changed the wiki to use some sort of Single-Sign On system. If I request that URL now I get a series of HTTP 302 redirects, going through the following Locations:

- `/sso?request_uri=/mainwiki/api.php?action=query&titles=SomePage&prop=info&format=xml`
- `http://wiki.intranet/sso/?request_uri=/mainwiki/api.php%3faction=query&titles=SomePage&prop=info&format=xml`
- `https://wiki.intranet/sso/?request_uri=/mainwiki/api.php%3faction=query&titles=SomePage&prop=info&format=xml`

When I request that last URL using cURL I get a 400 (Bad Request) response from the server. With the `-I` parameter to show the headers, here it is:

```
> curl -S -k -I -u "username:password" "https://wiki.intranet/sso/?request_uri=/mainwiki/api.php%3faction=query&titles=SomePage&prop=info&format=xml"
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2015 20:47:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

When I request that same URL using Google Chrome, however, I see the results that I want!

How do I get the information using `curl`?

---

**Edit:** When I request the original URL using Firefox, it also goes through the same redirects, and then shows me two 401 (Authorization Required) statuses. When I fill out the username/password in Firefox it takes me through another redirect ***back to the original url***, at which point it gets a status 200 response with the XML I want.

Comment: Oh, and I tried that final URL replacing the `&` with `%26` in case the Apache server processing the request was somehow choking on that. Same 400 result.

Comment: That looks like an issue with your company's SSO system, not with MediaWiki itself. Alas, that probably also means it can't really be answered without more information about the SSO implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got this to work by adding the following:

`curl -s -k`**`-L --ntlm -c cookies.txt`**`-u "user:pass" "originalurl"`

*Note that some pages suggest that you can use `-u :` on Windows to pass your credentials along. This did not work for me.*

This worked using the following curl version on Windows:

```
c:\> curl --version
curl 7.36.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.36.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: Largefile NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Comment: The [user manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) is your friend: *If you use an SSPI-enabled curl binary and do NTLM authentication, you can force curl to pick up the user name and password from your environment by simply specifying a single colon with this option: "-u :"* As you can see from the output of `--version`, the curl binary you use has been built without SSPI support.